# Solving simultaneous linear congruences for two unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, congruences

Find all pairs $(x,y)$ which solve

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
9x+20y&\equiv0\mod{29}\\
16x+13y&\equiv0\mod{29}
\end{align}
\right.
$$

So I have written this in the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}9&20\\16&13\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\mod{29}$$

But I notice that $\det{A}\equiv0\mod{29}$ so it is not invertible in $\mathbb{F}_{29}$. How do I find a solution to this? I have only been taught to find the inverse of the matrix to find $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Gaussian elimination. Put the system to row-echelon form.
Here there are only two rows, so it's easy. Multiply first row by the inverse of $9$ so you get $1$ in the so called pivot location. Now subtract the first row enough many times ($16$ in this case) from the second, so that you get $0$ under the $1$ in the first column.

Now when you have an non-invertible matrix, it happens that you get a zero-row (or you can't choose an invertible pivot variable). Hence you can introduce a free variable for that row, and that stays in the solution (so you have many possible solutions for each value of that free variable).

Comment: Using elementary row operations I find that $(x,y)=\lambda(-28,1)$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}_{29}$ however the answer is $(x,y)=\lambda(1,1)$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}_{29}$. What have I done wrong

Comment: @user2850514 But $-28=1$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_{29}$.